# vue plugin pwa sw.js not found

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, vue-cli

I have 1 app using the vue pwa plugin, it works great.

The vuejs config for the app looks like this:

```
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier')

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        implementation: require('sass')
      }
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuex-module-decorators',
    'vuex-persist'
  ],
  pwa: {
    name: 'MyApp',
    themeColor: '#000000',
    msTileColor: '#000000',
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

    // configure the workbox plugin
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
      swSrc: 'dev/sw.js',
      // ...other Workbox options...
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    devServer:{
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      new WebpackNotifierPlugin(),
    ],
    optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: 'single',
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: 3,
        minSize: 0,
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name(module) {
              const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
              return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I have another app, exactly the same, vue2, beufy etc etc.. i installed the same stuff via the vue pwa plugin and the config looks exactly the same but when i run build it says it cannot find the sw.js file:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'dev/sw.js'
```

I have created a uber basic vue app which does the same thing here: https://github.com/johndcarmichael/vue-pwa-sw-not-found

Has anyone else got this issue, and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not having `dev/sw.js` in your project, as you set in `swSrc`. `InjectManifest` means take this `sw.js` source file and write precache manifest into it, producing the final `service-worker.js` file.

Comment: ok but do you have a link to an exmaple service worker file that can be used with this plugin?

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/pwa.html#example-configuration  does not offer one

Comment: @John Just remove `workboxPluginMode` and `workboxOptions`. cli-plugin-pwa will use reasonable default values.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did not get that from the docs. Now everything works! No idea how the original app is building, but as I'm using the defaults I removed these opts from both configs and all is good.